# Cookie not set if Firefox 5

Tags: javascript, firefox, session-cookies

I've just discovered that a script that I have to set a cookie does not work in Firefox 5. It does work in Chrome, IE8 and FF4.

The page is on a sub-domain (foo.site.com)

The argument name is a string such as 'view123' and the val is a string that is either 'count' or 'percent'.

The cookie is supposed to expire at the end of the session hence no expiration date.

Below is my script:

```
function rtSetCookie(name, val){
    document.cookie = name + '=' + escape(val) + 
    ';expires="";path="/";';
 }
```

As I said it works fine in the other browsers not FF5 any ideas why?

Comment: User FireCookie to diagnose the problem. Maybe it's set, and the problem is something else :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like path is breaking when it has `" ".`

See this http://jsfiddle.net/fukhj/ Removing " works. Make sure you refresh the page twice because the second time reads the cookies.

Comment: Yes! That worked Amir! Removing the quotes in the path value solved it. Thank you!